# How can I add a slide title in wowchemy slides?

Tags: wowchemy

I use [wowchemy academic](https://github.com/wowchemy/starter-hugo-academic) theme for [wowchemy](https://wowchemy.com/) (Hugo static site generator) and I created a presentation with [slides](https://wowchemy.com/docs/content/slides/), how can I add custom titles to the slides ? The titles appear on the slide menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a custom slide title,you have to create an element with the class `menu-title` in your slide section and the element's text will be the title.

```
<span class="menu-title" style="display: none">Custom Title</span>
```